# Gson deserialize and serialize transient field

Tags: java, json, gson, transient

I have following Pojo Class with one field transient :

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String name;
    transient public UserSession[] bookings;
}
```

I want the transient filed be serialized and deserialized with Gson library but don't want the filed to be serialized on File.
How can i achieve it?

Comment: How about creating a custom serializer to serialize your class?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As stated [in the documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization):

> By default, if you mark a field as transient, it will be excluded.  As well, if a field is marked as "static" then by default it will be excluded. If you want to include some transient fields then you can do the following:
>
> import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
>
> Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
>       .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.STATIC)
>       .create();

Which will exclude `static` fields from Gson serialization, but not `transient` and `volatile` ones.

Comment: I can not get it to be recreated though. Annoying!